# How to add node color as attributes using Network X

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

How do I store NetworkX output not as .png or image files, but as an analyzable format with color as node attribute?

Below are the code used to draw NetworkX graph.

```
draw_networkx(
        graph,
        pos=graph.graph['positions'],
        node_color=graph.graph['colors'],
        labels=graph.graph['labels'],
        label=example_presentation,
        font_size=8,
        node_size=800
    )
```

`graph.graph['colors']` is

```
['#5B9BD5',
 '#E7E6E6',
 '#ff0000',
 '#70AD47',
 '#E7E6E6',
 '#ff0000',
 '#70AD47',
 '#E7E6E6',
 '#E7E6E6',
 '#E7E6E6',
 '#E7E6E6',
 '#E7E6E6',
 '#E7E6E6']
```

Comment: You mean something like object serialization?

Comment: I am not very familiar with the concept. Would it save "colors" as nodes' attributes and allow one to run analyses (e.g. centrality measure) on the saved graph?

Comment: How will you want to analyze the saved file later?  Reopen it as a networkx graph?

Comment: Yes, either reopen it as a networkX graph or edge list with color as node attributes would be fine.